# Data authorisation using WCF web services

Tags: asp.net, wcf, validation

I am new to web development and WCF. I am reading some basics about it and most of the things seem very interesting.

I have read that WCF services can be exposed using SOAP and other protocols. I was wondering whether there is an explicit implementation against data corruption during transmission built-in or it is left to user?

For example, if a service returns a string, what is the guarantee that it hasn't got corrupt during transmission (due to bad connectivity). This is not about detecting whether someone has hacked into system, I just want to ask about plain transmission errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean [message reliability](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=DW2ldput788C&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=wcf+message+reliability&source=web&ots=qi8sfpZMDM&sig=3UHgy0HJXmgwtRLnuzwR7GDhgkM&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=2&ct=result)?. If so, the link shows reliability for the different types of bindings.